Does Microsoft/Azure Support IPV6 only mesaging end points for Bot Services (Sep 2024)?
Does Microsoft/Azure Support IPV6 only end points for Bot Services Message End Points  (As of Sep 2024)?
To clarify, this messaging end point is on an IPV6 only load balancer.   AAAA records exist and reachability of the end point has been tested ok from other clients that have IPV6 support.  So the end point works fine on IPV6 from our vantage point.
However the bot end point is  not responding when the bot is tried to be reached via MS Teams
(Network Path is MS Teams client -> MS Teams Server -> MS Teams Bot Framework->Messaging End Point)

Other instances of the same app hosted behind an IPV4 load balancer are working fine on the path above.
No errors are evident from Azure Bot Services Portal.
Q:  Is IPV6 supported for Azure Bot Services?
Q:  If so, if you were successful, did you have to enable any further settings on the Azure end to make it work?
Our cloud provider has started to charge for IPV4 addresses so we are looking to migrate to IPV6 where possible.  In this case, this is a Server to Server communication path so not concerned about end users who are still IPV4 only as they do not interact with this end point.
Thanks

Yes, Microsoft has recognized the importance of IPv6 and has started to add support for IPv6 to its services, including Azure Bot Services. Please also refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/entra/entra-id/ad-dmn-services/azure-ad-ipv6-support

The question is specific to Bot Services which does not seem to work with IPV6 messaging end points.    The article you listed is for Entra ID and not Bot services?  Can you positively confirm that IPV6 is supported by bot services?

Azure Bot Services do not officially support IPv6-only messaging endpoints. The lack of responsiveness when connecting bots through IPv6-only load balancers, despite being reachable by other clients, aligns with current limitations in the Bot Framework, particularly when bots are integrated with Microsoft services like Teams.


However the bot end point is not responding when the bot is tried to be reached via MS Teams

This issue arises because Azure Bot Services currently do not fully support IPv6-only messaging endpoints. This limitation is particularly noticeable when bots are integrated with Microsoft services like Teams
Even though IPv6 may be increasingly supported by other Azure services, the Bot Framework’s reliance on IPv4 in certain scenarios can lead to the non-responsiveness you are experiencing.
For now, you may need to maintain an IPv4 load balancer or use a dual-stack (IPv4/IPv6) configuration to ensure compatibility with Microsoft Teams and other bot channels.

Thanks @Suresh.     That matches our lived experience.   Did you find an official Microsoft Page that has positive affirmations for services that are fully IPV6; and hopefully has a committed roadmap for others.
In terms of scenarios, most bot service scenarios are handled over https.    Do you know which scenarios rely on IPV4?  Media ?
We are not getting a response to even the most basic echo  bot scenarios when hosted in IPV6.

Azure Bot Services do not currently have official support for IPv6-only messaging endpoints, which aligns with the issues you're encountering when using an IPv6-only load balancer. support for services like Azure Application Gateway and Front Door, basic bot scenarios like the echo bot still rely heavily on IPv4 in many cases.

Media and more complex services indeed rely on IPv4, but even for basic HTTPS bot messaging endpoints, IPv6 support is not yet fully integrated. Unfortunately, Microsoft has not provided a clear roadmap for Bot Services IPv6 adoption. For now in the meantime, hybrid (dual-stack) configurations might be the best workaround.
